# How to reduce WhatsApp Desktop App RAM Usage?

Tags: windows, memory, whatsapp

**The WhatsApp** Desktop App is always open on my Windows 11 machine since it is a major work tool.
The problem is that it **is sacrificing 1GB of RAM**.

It consumes around 600MB to 1GB depending on its usage. Just get focus on the window, change between conversations and you can see it growing up memory on Task Manager.

[Here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/395288) there is a similar question, unanswered for mac.

**Is there any way to reduce the RAM consumed by WhatsApp App?**

Here are some images of the app running in Task Manager:

At Starting Up:
[image]

Getting focus, changing between conversations, rolling up and down the scroll bar, etc:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think there's a lot you can do other than reporting the issue to it's developer.

Comment: Are you sure you're reporting *RAM* usage and not virtual memory usage? Can you include some images showing the consumption as people frequently misunderstand what these tools are reporting.

Comment: I've added some images

Comment: IIRC Windows Task Manager shows the Resident Set Size in this column. // There is nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

I found two workarounds for this problem.

1-Open the WhatsApp Web in the Edge browser and create an app.
-On the Edge go to `...(three dots) -> App -> Install this site as an app`.
Edge browser makes better memory usage, and when the app is minimized it puts it in economy mode.

2-Configure Nvidia GPU to run the app.
On Nvidia Control Panel (search for it on the Windows start menu)
go to `Panel navigation tree pane -> under 3D Settings -> select Manage 3D settings -> Program Settings tab`. and configure the WhatsApp to use the GPU.

By switching to a GPU render engine, WhatsApp will be able to utilize some of the memory on your graphics card and free up space in your system's RAM.
Unfortunately, changing the GPU render engine will only work if you have a graphics card.

[Run a program on Nvidia GPU](https://www.nvidia.com/content/Control-Panel-Help/vLatest/en-us/mergedProjects/nv3d/to_configure_uniques_3D_settings_for_my_applications_and_gamess.htm)